# PHP struct initialization like in C#

Tags: c#, php, struct

I have found example how to initialize PHP class:

```
class MyStruct {
    public $foo;
    public $bar;
}

$obj = new MyStruct();
$obj->foo = 'Hello';
$obj->bar = 'World';
```

Is there a some simpler (without repeating $obj) way in PHP like in C#?

```
 var obj = new MyStruct()
 {
    foo = 'Hello',
    bar = 'World',
 }
```

Comment: Just give your class a constructor (__construct) and pass in the stuff you want to set on instantiation as arguments